# change cell values of all tables to zero

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have databases of users like below

```
good_user_mike
good_user_thomas
good_user_stevie
good_user_jhonathan
```

each database contains several tables eg `cpd,ce,ct,cg,cb,fd,gf`... which are all similar
they all contain a column names called

```
time,visitors,clicks,leads
1,12,42,12
2,12,45,25
3,42,45,43
..
.
.
```

Now my question is ,I want to make the row with `time = 3` of all tables of all databases to zero so that becomes

```
   time,visitors,clicks,leads
    1,12,42,12
    2,12,45,25
    3,0,0,0
    ..
    .
    .
```

is it possible to make every row with time = 3 to zero?

what I tried:

```
$hour = "3";
$sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {


    echo $row[0];

$slink_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$row[0]} WHERE timespan LIKE '%{$hour}%'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$slink_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_array( $slink_query );
$slink = "0";

mysql_query("UPDATE `$row[0]`
    SET `visits` = {$slink}
    WHERE timespan LIKE '%{$hour}%'");
echo $slink;

    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `LIKE` if you want to match the time exactly. `time LIKE '%{$hour}'` will match any time with a `3` in it, e.g. `13`, `30`, `103`, etc. Just use `=` to match the time.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $table = $row['TABLE_NAME'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `$table`
                SET visitors = $slink, clicks = $slink, leads = $slink
                WHERE time = $hour");
}
```

There's also no need to do a `SELECT` query first. You never do anything with the result of that query.

To update tables in different databases, you need to get the `TABLE_SCHEMA` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';
```

Then you can do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $table = $row['TABLE_NAME'];
    $db = $row['TABLE_SCHEMA'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `$db`.`$table`
                SET visitors = $slink, clicks = $slink, leads = $slink
                WHERE time = $hour");
}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Mnr5Hw93 please visit my problem is not solved... I get error..

Comment: There was a missing `)`. I fixed it.

Comment: sir, the problem now is I am able to change the value of one database i.e mysql_select_db($dbname, $connect); Its not changing other databases..Please help.